# rpm: what determines whether a package updates a previous one or gets installed in addition

Tags: package-management, rpm, dependencies

Is it simply the installation path?  If that is the case then any package that has version in the name/path will never update another, so that cannot be it.  I don;t see a mention of this in the manual dependency info.  When creating an RPM, how do I tell cAPI-3.1.6-x86_64.rpm that it is supposed to update cAPI-2.1.7-x86_64.rpm when I install it, not create a new path under /usr/lib and ignore the existing package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally agreeing with [@msuchy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/100010/msuchy) that the relevant feature is the combination of package *name* and *architecture*, it helps to give some overview.

The place to look for information is not "upgrade", but *installing multiple versions* of a package:

[Multiple Installed Versions](http://rpm.org/user_doc/multiple_versions.html) (on rpm.org) gives a good overview:

> *All of the package management tools operate using certain keys to refer to packages/programs. Normally that key is package* *name* *or package* **name** *and package* **arch**

That is, there are two choices (normally): package name by itself, or package name in combination with architecture.  It goes on to say

> *kernel packages are built specifically so they do not offer any conflicting files from one version of the kernel to the next*

That is, kernels are treated specially because it is known (to the package developers) that all of the files in a Linux kernel package have distinct names (either the filenames have the version embedded, or the files live in directories with the version embedded).  That is one special case.  Too many special cases makes work for RPM's maintainers.

It goes on to show how packages for programs with long-term stable versions are built using those version numbers as part of the package *name*, thereby allowing for multiple versions of the program to be installed on the same machine.  The example given is for python.  Other programs which you might see using the same scheme include apache, autoconf, gcc, java.  Here are a few examples from Fedora22:

```
SDL2-2.0.3-5.fc22.x86_64
openjpeg2-2.1.0-6.fc22.x86_64
pygobject2-2.28.6-13.fc22.x86_64
pygobject3-3.16.2-1.fc22.x86_64
pygobject3-base-3.16.2-1.fc22.x86_64
python3-3.4.2-6.fc22.x86_64
qt5-qtbase-5.5.0-15.fc22.x86_64
vte291-0.40.2-1.fc22.x86_64
vte3-0.36.4-1.fc22.x86_64
webkitgtk3-2.4.9-1.fc22.x86_64
webkitgtk4-2.8.5-2.fc22.x86_64
```

When you see these packages, it is easy to become confused about which numbers are part of the package name, and which are the *version* and *release*.  RPM uses dashes (`-`) to separate these: if there is no dash, the number is part of the name.

Answer (score 1):

It is the `%{name}.%{arch}` combination. If this is the same then it is upgrade. If it differs then it is another installation.

I.e. you can have `cAPI-3.1.6-x86_64` and `cAPI-3.1.6-i386` installed concurrently. But you can not have `cAPI-3.1.6-x86_64` and `cAPI-2.1.7-x86_64` on one system (unless you do really dirty tricks).